# AttributeError: 'SparseCategoricalCrossentropy' object has no attribute '__name__'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I encountered this error in a basic CNN:

> AttributeError: 'SparseCategoricalCrossentropy' object has no attribute '**name**'

I thought you could set `loss=tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()` in `model.compile()`?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tf.random.set_seed(42)

train, test = tfds.load('fashion_mnist', split=['train', 'test'], as_supervised=True)

train = train.map(lambda x, y: (tf.divide(x, 255), y)).batch(8)
test = test.map(lambda x, y: (tf.divide(x, 255), y)).batch(8)

custom_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')])

custom_model.compile(loss=tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
                     optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),
                     metrics=[tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])

early_stopping = [tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=5)]

conv_dropout_history = custom_model.fit(train, validation_data=test,
                                        epochs=100, callbacks=early_stopping)
```

Is there any way to use this object in `model.compile()` or should I only ever use `tf.metrics.sparse_categorical_crossentropy` (or the string form)?

Comment: I think the problem is you're using metrics as loss. Try `tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()` instead

Comment: I am not a smart man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a metric as a loss function.

Try replacing this:

```
tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
```

With this:

```
tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
```

The [metric](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy) can't be minimized by the Keras optimizer, so you have to use the [loss function](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#sparsecategoricalcrossentropy-class).